# Not able to display the count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to show the number of episodes whose title contain the words “on” and “ol”.

Using CTE from the table :- [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2355n.png)

I tried the following code but it is throwing error:

```
select 
    count (select Title from tblEpisode 
           where Title like '%on%' or Title like '%ol%') 
from tblEpisode
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What is the problem? Please help!

Comment: no need to use CTE in this case. But you want to apply CTE for learning purpose. WITH t_cte AS (select   count(*) from     dbo.tblEpisode where    Title like '%on%' or Title like '%ol%') SELECT * FROM t_cte; Don't apply CTE where it's not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the problem?

For each row `count` expects either a `*` or a scalar expression and will count the rows where that scalar expression is `not null`. In your SQL, the expression is not a scalar, but a sub-select.

> How can [I] do it with [a] CTE?

Some possibilities: **All of these contrived examples make the code worse than without the CTE.**

```
WITH filtered AS (SELECT *
    FROM dbo.tblEpisode
    WHERE Title LIKE '%on%'
    OR Title LIKE '%ol%')
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM filtered;

WITH getCount AS (SELECT Count(*) AS CountStar
    FROM dbo.tblEpisode
    WHERE Title LIKE '%on%'
    or Title LIKE '%ol%')
SELECT *
FROM getCount;

WITH cte AS (SELECT *
    FROM dbo.tblEpisode)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE Title LIKE '%on%'
or Title LIKE '%ol%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't want a subquery at all here. Add a `WHERE` to your outer query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.tblEpisode
WHERE Title LIKE '%on%'
   or Title LIKE '%ol%';
```

Comment: Thats make sense! How can i do it with CTE?

Comment: Why do you need a CTE? Where does that requirement come from @Ashish ? There's literally no need for a CTE for such a simple query.

Comment: This question can be done without CTE. But since I am practicing SQL, I want to try same questions in different ways to learn more @Larnu

Comment: There's no need for a CTE here, @Ashish . Though, if you want to know how to write a CTE, look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I know there's no need of cte but i wanna practice CTE so I am asking @Larnu

Comment: So read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), @Ashish . it comes with plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples). [so] isn't a tutorial website; we're not here to answer your moving goal posts nor teach you. We're here to answer your **specific** questions; it's you who need to go off and learn the language you're writing, and if you have new questions, you ask a new question.

Comment: What can i write in the with part of cte for this question?!

Comment: @Ashish , this answers the question as is; there's no need for a CTE (as I have explained multiple times). If you want to implement CTEs, and you're having problems, you need to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), explaining your new requirements, showing your new attempts, and explaining why it isn't working. Don't forget to include *why* you need a CTE as well.

Comment: And learn what a CTE is, the basic syntax, and how to write / use them. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to your SQL fundamentals...

```
select   -- the data you want
from     -- the relevant tables
where    -- the conditions you want to apply
```

- What do you want to select? A count of the rows. `count(*)`
- What are the relevant tables? `dbo.tblEpisode`
- What conditions do you want to apply? `title like '%on%' or title like '%ol%'`

```
select   count(*)
from     dbo.tblEpisode
where    Title like '%on%' or Title like '%ol%';
```